# How to mock static method called in static method?

Tags: java, junit4, powermockito

I would like to make some JUnit tests, but I've problems connecting to the database.

I want to test the method : `getAndSavePlant`

```
public class App
{
    private static Connection connection = null;
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            log.info("Le driver MySQL JDBC est bien enregistré.");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            log.info("Erreur, le driver JDBC est introuvable. Assurez-vous d'avoir ajouter le driver JDBC aux dépendances Maven correctement. ", e);
            return;
        }   

       try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("databaseUrl", "user", "password");
            log.info("La connexion à la base de données a réussi. (" + connection.getMetaData().getURL() + ")");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("La connexion à la base de données a échoué ! (" + connection.getMetaData().getURL() + ")");
            throw new SQLException();
        }


        getAndSavePlant();
    }

    public static void getAndSavePlant() {
        if(...)
            getFruitName("1");
        else if(...)
            getTreeName("4");
        else if(...){
            getFlowerName("7");


        saveRecord(values);         
    }
}
```

With for example `getFruitName()`:

```
public static String getFruitName(String idFruit) {
    try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT name FROM fruit WHERE id = ?")) {
        pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(idFruit));
        try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
            if(rs.next())
                return rs.getString("name");
            else
                return null;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("getFruitName => SQL Exception" ,e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

But there is a problem with the `connection` object which is `null`.

So i tried to mock the methods contained in `getAndSavePlant` with the following code :

```
@Test
public void testGetAndSaveFruit(){
    try {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(App.class);

        PowerMockito.when(App.class, "getFruitName", "1").thenReturn("Apple");
        PowerMockito.when(App.class, "getFruitName", "7").thenReturn("Strawberry");
        PowerMockito.when(App.class, "getTreeName", "2").thenReturn("pine");
        PowerMockito.when(App.class, "getTreeName", "4").thenReturn("oak");
        PowerMockito.when(App.class, "getFlowerName", "1").thenReturn("Rose");
        PowerMockito.when(App.class, "getFlowerName", "4").thenReturn("orchid");            
        App.getAndSavePlant();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Assert.fail("Error");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the call to `getAndSavePlant` does nothing.

How could I mock only inside calls to static methods ?

Comment: where is `connection` coming from in the shown code?

Comment: Given that you have this information coming from the database, mocking the connection out is the ***last*** thing you want to do.  How do you get a connection object to begin with?

Comment: I've edited my post to show you the connection initialization in the main method

Comment: Why would mocking the connection would be bad ? Because we want to test our code without being dependant to any database.
Is this a bad idea ?

Comment: You are setting yourself up for problems in the future. Consider reviewing your design choice and refactor that code to be more SOLID and not so tightly coupled to implementation concerns that make testing difficult.. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: you may refer this before proceeding: http://williamdurand.fr/2013/07/30/from-stupid-to-solid-code/

Comment: You're on a very slippery slope. Static methods in general can't be mocked. For more details please take a look at this excellent article by Miško Hevery http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/